# Como converter caracteres dentro do XML?

Tags: php, xml, web-service

Eu tenho um código que está me dando problemas porque está gerando erros na execução. Eu preciso que o `XML` converta ou substitua caracteres mas não sei fazer isso em tempo de execução. Estou tentando fazer assim mas sem sucesso.

```
<?php

// Receberá todos os dados do XML
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>';

// Raiz do documento XML
$xml .= '<Imobiliaria>';

// Loop dos valores
for ( $i = 0; $i<count($res)-1; $i++ ) {

    $xml .= '<Imovel>';

    $xml.="<DESCRICAO>".$res[$i]["Descricao"]."</DESCRICAO>";

    $xml.= preg_replace('/&(?!#?[a-z0-9]+;)/', '&amp;', $xml);

    $xml.= '</Imovel>';

$xml .= '<Imobiliaria>';

?>
```

Preciso saber exatamente aonde, como e variáveis necessárias neste código para **substituir** ou **converter** os caracteres e eliminar os erros na geração do meu `XML`, este:

```
$xml.= preg_replace('/&(?!#?[a-z0-9]+;)/', '&amp;', $xml);
```

Comment: Cara voce esta criando o XML na mão?
Se for de uma olhada nestes artigos:
[artigo 1](http://www.itsalif.info/content/php-5-domdocument-creating-basic-xml)
[artigo 2](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/br/library/os-xmldomphp/)

e de uma olhada se vai te ajudar a construir o documento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta usar [**utf8_decode**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.utf8-decode.php)

```
echo utf8_decode( 'dormitÃ³rios' );
```

Output: *dormitórios*